# EC2 deployment with CloudStack

Tags: deployment, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud, citrix

I was wondering if it's possible to deploy a machine to a Amazon EC2 with cloudstack.
I know that cloudstack has an AWS compatible api through cloud-bridge but I do not want to manage cloudstack infrastructure but manage my AWS cloud from the cloudstack interface.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@Donal Lafferty is correct -- you cannot use CloudStack to provision Amazon EC2 instances, but the main reason is that CloudStack is designed to be a tool for cloud/IaaS providers, not consumers. In other words, if you wanted to operate a private cloud inside your company or offer a public cloud service to compete with Amazon, CloudStack would be a good fit. OpenStack and VMware vCloud Director are two other options in this same space.

It sounds like you're looking for a tool to help with provisioning and managing EC2 instances. If you need something beyond the AWS Console, you might want to check out [Scalr](http://scalr.net/), [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com/), or the [Puppet Cloud Provisioner](http://puppetlabs.com/solutions/ec2/). All three of these focus on working with Amazon AWS, but they also offer support for CloudStack if you ever want an alternative cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment, because the CloudStack GUI speaks to the management server using the CloudStack API.

Answer (score 0):

To be really cloud independent and being able to deploy your applications on any cloud provider, or even in bare metal with just one click or command you can use [ElasticBox](http://elasticbox.com): AWS EC2, Cloudstack, VMware, Google Compute, Softlayer, Openstack and many others are supported cloud providers.

Here is a tutorial of how simple is to deploy on AWS EC2 with it:

https://elasticbox.com/documentation/deploying-and-managing-instances/using-your-aws-account/